# Get the value for multiple <p:rating>

Tags: jsf

I have a list of rating criteria on which I am using `<c:forEach>`. How can I get the values of  of multiple selected rating option? Right now i am getting null value.

**XHTML Page**

```
<h:form>
   <c:forEach var="item" items="#{productManagedBean.categoryratingcriterias}">
      <h6>#{item.ratingCriteriaId.criteriaName}</h6>
         <p:rating id="rating" value="#{reviewxcriteriaManagedBean.rate}" stars="10">
           <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{reviewxcriteriaManagedBean.onrate}" update="messages" />
           <p:ajax event="cancel" listener="#{reviewxcriteriaManagedBean.oncancel}" update="messages" />
         </p:rating>
   </c:forEach>
</h:form>
```

**ManagedBean**

```
@Named(value = "reviewxcriteriaManagedBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ReviewxcriteriaManagedBean {

private Integer rate;

public Integer getRate() {
    return rate;
}

public void setRate(Integer rate) {
    this.rate = rate;
}

public void onrate(RateEvent<Integer> rateEvent) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Rate Event", "You rated:" + rateEvent.getRating());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}

public void oncancel() {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cancel Event", "RateReset");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you get null with all your ratings, from the first to the last? Is an option moving ratings from bean `reviewxcriteriaManagedBean` to the single item of `productManagedBean.categoryratingcriterias` list?

Comment: All your ratings refer to the same bean/value. Tried with a plain inputText? Same problem.... Narrow down problems... There are existing duplicates about this in stackoverflow...

Comment: yes i am getting null from all ratings. no there is no option because i have one click event which is occured on commandLink in `productManagedBean` in which i have got `Collection<Categoryratingcriteria>` @WoAiNii